# Running a Python program command without installing it

Tags: python

I'm trying to run [CairoSVG](http://cairosvg.org/) but I don't have permission on the server to run it. No problem I think, I've used other libraries in Python before without installing them by pointing sys.path.append to their directory path:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/full/path/to/SomeOtherLibrary")
import SomeOtherLibrary
```

I thought I could create something like `loader.py`, import the path inside there to CairoSVG with a sys.path.append, then instead of calling: `cairosvg image.svg -o image.png` I could call `/full/path/to/loader.py image.svg -o image.png`.

Then I started to create loader.py and thought I have no idea what to do or if this is even possible. I figured I start with:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/full/path/to/CairoSVG")
```

And then I don't know what. If I was able to install the script I'd need to pass parameters to it. How can I create a loader to run this library?

Answer (score 0):

Simply call `cairosvg.main()` from your script. Pretty much like it is done here: https://github.com/Kozea/CairoSVG/blob/master/cairosvg.py